# Yii Curl wrapper set Authorization header

Tags: php, curl, yii, authorization, token

I've been using this Curl wrapper in Yii : [hackerone curl](https://github.com/hackerone/curl/)

I am trying to send authorization bearer token in header with this code:

```
$auth = array("Authorization: Bearer".$token);
// I am tried this too
//$auth = array("Authorization" => "Bearer".$token);
$jsonObject = Yii::app()->curl->setOption(CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $auth)->get($url);
```

But I got same error result, the error says :

```
Undefined index: scheme 
Error in Curl.php line 93 <- that wrapper
```

Does anyone got this problem too?

I have not found the right code for this problem.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I have check the code in hackernon curl. I think the problem is that `$url` value doesn't have schema like `http://`.

```
$url = 'http://www.google.com' // good 
$url = 'www.google.com' // bad
```